# Question on power adapters

Tags: charging

I would like to buy a second charger for my MacBook Air M1. On its back I read that it supports: 20V, 1.5A (30W) and 20.3V, 3A (~60W).

I have read other questions and answers here, but my question is more specific and it does not apply to MacBook Airs only.

What data should I look at when shopping for a new charger, especially when not made by Apple?

For example, does the following charger support the 60W requirement of my MBA M1 ?

[image]

There is a mode with 20V, 5A: in this case will the MBA M1 be able to negotiate 20V, 3A? Should I prefer a 65W adapter with 20V/3.25A ?

Answer (score 3):

If this charger meets the requirements of the USB-C specs, and it has a ***higher*** power rating than Apple's 65W charger, it will work. Power supply/charger ratings are given as "safe maximum" ratings; that is, they can safely supply power **up to** their rated value.

It is the device being charged/powered that determines how much power is actually drawn from the charger - not the charger itself. Chargers do not "force-feed" power to the load; it does not operate in the manner of [gavage does in Foie gras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras)  **:)** . If you connected your 100W USB-C charger to a device (designed for using a USB-C charger) that only used 1 Watt, it would be fine.

Note this *USB-C compliance* caveat is very important because USB-C specs allow the charger to deliver up to 20V ***if*** the load signals that it is USB-C compliant. If the load does not signal the USB-C charger IAW the specifications, the USB-C charger falls back to 5V - the same output voltage as earlier USB devices provide.

Comment: Yup. I always described it that Amps (& consequently Watts) are *pulled* by the device, whereas Volts are *pushed* by the charger. This is why 'too many amps' is quite safe, but 'too many volts' is not.

Comment: @Tetsujin, That's a good way to think of it, but sometimes eyes glaze over talking about volts & amps. I read about foie gras some time ago & thought that might be a better analogy... lol

Comment: For sure - but it's always good to know that Amps & Watts are kind of related, whereas Volts act differently in many respects.

Comment: @Tetsujin, In what sense? They're both required for power...

Comment: W=V*A. One is 'a consequence of the other' but they act differently, as my first comment. Volts are pushed, Amps are pulled, the result is Watts.

Comment: @Tetsujin: That's true, but electrical current (a change in current) can also "cause" a voltage; e.g. L*di/dt. After years in university & a career, I am still looking forward to the day I can say, "I understand how all of that works"  :)

Comment: That's inductance, which is frankly beyond me, other than I know it's what makes transformers, speakers & microphones work ;)

Comment: "I know just enough to be dangerous!" :) When I have to, I can work through the basic physics... the physical world is governed by "natural laws", which are consistent & reliable. Software on the other hand - not governed by natural laws.     The bot is squawking about extended discussions now & I s'pose we're a bit out of bounds.